# Efficiently Calculate the Difference Between Two Vectors

Tags: java, vector, 3d

I am writing a three dimensional framework that consists of polygon surfaces arranged at various angles. In a certain section of my code, I want to calculate the brightness of the surface based on a light source whose angle is given by a vector.

More specifically, The orientation of the surface is represented by a vector, and the light source is also given by a vector. By common knowledge, the surface is brightest when the light is shining directly on it, or when the difference in the angles of the vectors is 0.

However, in my current solution, I need to calculate atan() six times for every light to obtain the difference, which is computationally inefficient.

Is there a better way?

Comment: I think you should use the dot product between your light source vector and a versor representing the plane. It's just 3 multiplications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is.  Look up [Lambert's cosine law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert%27s_cosine_law).  It says that the intensity of light from a diffuse surface is simply the cosine of the angle between the light vector (pointing towards the light source) and the normal vector from the plane.  So, all you need to do is normalize the vectors and take the dot product.